# How to get the messages between two users after a particular time stamp in ejabberd through iq stanzas?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

Is there any iq stanza in ejabberd that returns messages between two users after a particular timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [mod_mam](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-mam) is enabled and used to store those messages, take a look at the protocol section [4.1.2 Filtering by time received](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#filter-time)

Comment: This query returns the messages after a timestamp for a user. But I need to get these messages between two users.